# Jquery Ajax data not sent through multiple tabs

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery Ajax to send my parameters to backend in java and return value is of `JSON` type. My application has different categories which uses the same **jsp**. If i open a single category in one tab everything is working fine. But when i open different categories in different tabs, the last opened tab/category only sends parameters to the back end, the first opened tabs triggers the ajax call, but the parameters passed are not available in the back end. PFB the code snippet of the AJAX call made,

```
function addThings(things) {
$(document).ready(function() {
                            var parameters = {
                                  _method : 'put'
                            };
                            for ( var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {

                                  if (parameters[things[i][0]] != null) {
                                        parameters[things[i][0]] = parseInt(parameters[things[i][0]])
                                                    + parseInt(things[i][1]);
                                  } else {
                                        parameters[things[i][0]] = things[i][1];
                                  }
                            }

                            $.ajax({
                                  type : "POST",
                                  url : "addThings.do",
                                  async : false,
                                  data : parameters,
                                  datType : "json",
                                  failure : function(data) {
                                        ShowFatalError();
                                  },
                                  success : function(response) {
                                        var resp =$.getJSON(response);
                                        if (resp == null) {
                                              ShowFatalError();
                                        } else {
                                              if (response.exceptionsOccured) {
                                                    ShowFatalError();
                                              }
                                              CurrentJSON = response;
                                              CountDisplay(CurrentJSON);
                                              return (CurrentJSON);
                                        }
                                  }
                              });
                        });

return CurrentJSON;
}
```

The above function is triggered on a button click.
Please help me out in this.

Comment: show your code which you are using to open in new tab

Comment: I am not using any code to open new tab... Both are diff URLs and I open that manually... But ajax call in the second loaded page works fine... But in first tab it is not taking the parameters to backend

Comment: Why document.ready inside a function? datType should be dataType. You need to goto the developer console in your brwoser and see the network tab to find out if you are sending the parameters.